# Remove header from laravel markdown template

Tags: laravel, email, markdown

I'm trying to remove the header part from laravel's markdown template but it's not working, I published the files into my vendor folder and all.

This is my message component:

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }}

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} {{ env('APP_NAME') }}.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

And my layout file:

```
{!! strip_tags($slot) !!}
@isset($subcopy)

{!! strip_tags($subcopy) !!}
@endisset

{!! strip_tags($footer) !!}
```

Any help?

Also, is it possible to make my own markdown template without using default layout? I tried adding laravel markdown components directly into my mail blade.php files but everything lookied like trash and uncentered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those the `mail/text/` files that you edited? Have you tried also removing the header from the `mail/html/` files?

Comment: These are from vendor/markdown folders

Answer (score 5):

### **Using change mark down template**

1. You need to fire **php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail** command on project root using terminal
2. After executed above command, generate some blade file on below path: **resources/views/vendor/mail/html**
3. Remove code from **header.blade.php**.

---

### **Using custom mail template**

- Also you can send mail using custom mail template. see below code.

  `Mail::send([YOUR TEMPLATE], [DATA], function ($m) use ($user) {
      $m->from('[FROM_MAIL]',[FROM_NAME]);
      $m->to([TO_EMAIL])->subject([SUBJECT]);
  });`